# .NET Core and New Relic integration

Tags: .net-core, newrelic

So we developed a .NET Core 6.0 app and we are deploying to Cloudfoundry using manifest.yml

I downloaded the buildpack for new-relic-dotnet-buildpack-1.1.9.pivotal

I want to understand how to implement this in our manifest.yml file so we can integrate the New Relic to our .NETCore APIs.

Here is our manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name: pmt-api
  buildpacks:
    - dotnet_core_buildpack
  stack: cflinuxfs3
  memory: 2G
  env:
    NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY: 68d93d382301e2155f7f67097ad65dcd6db76cde
    NEW_RELIC_ACCOUNT_ID: 1737703
    NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME: gwam-asia-pmt-uat-api
    NEW_RELIC_DISTRIBUTED_TRACING_ENABLED: true
    CACHE_NUGET_PACKAGES: false
    GRANT_TYPE: client_credentials
    SSO_AUTHORITIES: pmt-api.read, pmt-api.scheduled-task, uaa.resource
    SSO_IDENTITY_PROVIDERS: manulife-adfs-uat
    SSO_RESOURCES: |
      pmt-api.read: Read access
      pmt-api.write: Write access
      pmt-api.admin: Admin access
      pmt-api.scheduled-task: Special role for scheduled tasks
  routes:
  - route: pmt-api-uat.apps.cac.pcf.manulife.com
  services:
  - pmt-api-config
  - pmt-sso
  - pmt-newrelic
```

I wanted to have APM data in New Relic for our .NETCore APIs